# Jquery. Добавление параметра в href к ссылкам с определенным id

Tags: jquery, href, атрибуты

Здравствуйте, 
На странице есть ссылки вида:

```
<a class="ifr" id="popup" href="/article/234">Текст</a>
<a class="ifr" id="popup" href="/article/235">Текст</a>
...
```

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на ссылки с данным id к href в конце дописывался еще один параметр? 
Например: /article/235/popup
Но вид самой ссылки для пользователя и поисковиков не должен меняться...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#popup").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr('href') + '/popup');
    });
});
```

Такой скрипт **не подходит** - он меняет все ссылки изначально... а мне нужно только по клику. Чтобы пользователь не мог видеть и копировать такие ссылки.

**В идеале бы сделать ссылки вида**

```
<a class="ifr" hrefattrs="/cmd=PopLayer" id="popup" href="/article/235">Текст</a>
```

А при нажатии на ссылку к href если установлено значение hrefattrs присоединялось hrefattrs.

Подскажите как реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.ifr").click(function(){
    var newUrl = $(this).attr('href') + $(this).attr('hrefattrs');
    console.log(newUrl);
    window.location.href = newUrl;
    return false;
  });
});
```

Не дублируйте `id` DOM-элементов.

Comment: левые атрибуты таки лучше в `data-` запихать, автор вряд ли про такое знает, поэтому и просто вписал сразу.

Comment: teran, я вкурсе про data-href=""...
Просто подглянул у одноклассников hrefattrs=""

Comment: @Igor, странно, но не работает.
Просто переходит по ссылке из href не добавляя ничего.

Comment: В принципе работает
        $(this).attr("href",$(this).attr('href') + $(this).attr('hrefattrs'));
 return false;

Но добавляет undefined естественно когда не указан hrefattrs
И дублирует hrefattrs при повторном нажатии... (например если пользователь открыть по _blank, а потом вернулся и нажал еще раз) :( 
Кто знает как решить?

Comment: @Igor Благодарю за желание помочь...
Есть пара вопросов: 
1. А если hrefattrs не задан? - будет ошибка undefined
2. Есть ли какая то замена location.href в этом случае... т.к после клика данная ссылка у меня открывается в iframe через fancybox... а при location.href будет просто скидывать на редирект.